# Get overridden property attribute

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, custom-attributes, system.reflection

I have a custom attribute like this:

```
public class PropertyInfoAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool IsAutoComplete { get; set; }
}
```

And there is a class like this:

```
public class Article
{
    public virtual int Order { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

In another class,which inherits from Article, I override Order property and declare the attribute for it like this:

```
public class ArticleDetails : Article
{
    [PropertyInfo(IsAutoCompele = true)]
    public override int Order { get; set; }
}
```

The problem appears when I want to get attributes by using the GetCustomAttributes method in PropertyInfo class. I do it like this:

```
PropertyInfo propInfo = //do something for getting property info from the
                        //ArticleDetails class;

var attr = propInfo.GetCustomAttribute<PropertyInfoAttribute>();
```

But it returns nothing! I don't know why!

**UPDATE:**

I get property info in this method:

```
    public static void InitPropertyInfoAttribute<TModel, TProperty>(MvcHtmlString source, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        PropertyInfo propInfo = (expression.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
    }
```

Comment: Can you include the code for getting `propInfo`? You need to be getting the info from the `Order` property, not the `ArticleDetails` class itself.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I've updated, thanks

Comment: I think you need to cut this down to something that just gets the property directly. I suspect your code above is ending up with something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem hides in here:

```
PropertyInfo propInfo = //do something for getting property info from the
                        //ArticleDetails class;
```

I presume that you actually obtain this property info from `Article` class, not `ArticleDetails` and that's  why it returns null. The following snippet worked as expected for me:

```
PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(ArticleDetails).GetProperty("Order");
var attr = propInfo.GetCustomAttribute<PropertyInfoAttribute>();
```

---

**Update**

---

According to your update - the problem is that `Member` property of the `MemberExpression` points to the `Article` type;

As a solution to this you can update your `InitPropertyInforAttribute` as follows:

```
MemberExpression memberExpression = (expression.Body as MemberExpression);
return typeof(TModel).GetProperty(memberExpression.Member.Name);
```

And don't forget that you should pass `ArticleDetails` as first generic type parameter - `InitPropertyInfoAttribute<ArticleDetails, propertyType>`.

Comment: yes it's because of getting Property info, but as you see in my Update I try to get property info from a Expression method. How can I obtain property info like u? thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I can't reproduce the error. Attribute is extracted. Could you provide the details?

```
// Your classes
public class PropertyInfoAttribute: Attribute {
  public bool IsAutoComplete {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public class Article {
  public virtual int Order {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public class ArticleDetails: Article {
  [PropertyInfo(IsAutoComplete = true)]
  public override int Order {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

...

// My test

// Let's do it explicitly:
// ask for public and instance (not static) property
PropertyInfo pi = typeof(ArticleDetails).GetProperty("Order", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
// Then ask for the attribute
Attribute at = pi.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(PropertyInfoAttribute));

// And, finally, check if attribute is existing
// ... And so, assertion passes - attribute is existing
Trace.Assert(!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, at), "No Attribute found.");
```